# Is there any pair of non-exponential strictly increasing functions $f$ and $g$ which $f . g$ is strictly increasing also?

Tags: calculus, functions

If we have two exponential functions like $f(x)=2^x$ and $g(x)=3^x$, $f.g$ will be strictly increasing like $f$ and $g$.

But I want to know is there any pair of *non-exponential* strictly increasing functions $f$ and $g$ ($D_f=D_g=\mathbb{R}$) which $f . g$ is strictly increasing also? Can anyone find an exmaple of such functions?

Comment: What about $f=g=\text{arctan}+\frac{1}{2}\pi$?

Comment: @Hyperplane You have to shift arctan by a constant to get a positive function, because otherwise you end up multiplying two negative numbers and getting a positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=g(x)=\frac {x\cdot |x|}{1+x^2}+1$ are strictly increasing and non-exponential (in fact, they are bounded). So is their product.

Comment: It seems to me that one way of doing this is to find a function which is positive and strictly increasing, and any two such functions would multiply to a similarly positive and strictly increasing function. I was going to use a shifted version of arctan to the same effect as your example. Another way would be to take an odd function which grows rapidly enough and multiply it by a suitable strictly positive increasing function.

Answer (score 0):

Take any two strictly increasing cumulative distribution functions on the real line.